# Deserealizar xml a objeto c# (xml no siempre tiene todos los nodos)

Tags: c#, xml

tengo que deserealizar un XML a un objeto de una clase definida, el problema es el siguiente: suponiendo la clase tiene 3 atributos (a, b y c), los xml vienen con los 3 atributos y es fácil deserealizarlos al objeto, mi inconveniente es que en algunas ocasiones el XML no viene con todos los nodos completos, por decir solo viene con el nodo a y c, entonces como hago para deserealizarlo a un objeto y para el nodo que no tiene poner null por ejemplo u otro valor por defecto.

Comment: use tipos nuleables como `int?`, `float?`, `Datetime?`, el framework, se encargara de establecer los valores `null` para los elementos o atributos que no estén presentes en el xml

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir la propiedad [IsNullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx) en el `XmlElementAttribute` definido. Por ejemplo:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   public string Campo1;
   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   public string Campo2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si no lo has podido resolver utilizando los atributos que te comentan arriba. Yo utilizaría los atributos DataContract y DataMember y me crearía mi propio deserializador.

Pero, si lo que estás es consumiento un xml de algún recurso externo en lugar de serializarlo directamente puedes obtener la respuesta y manualmente con un método de ayuda asignar los valores y así podrás establecer valores para cuando venga null alguno de los valores.

PD: Si lo que quieres es cargar un xml y cargar sus valores en un objeto pues entonces utiliza linq to XML:
[MSDN Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx)